# Return to scroll position after the page has been scrolled to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position

I am trying to make a sidebar only appear when a relevant button is clicked, on small devices, but I'm facing some difficulties.

I found a way to toggle its class to make it dis/appear on click and to automatically scroll the page back to top once this is done, so that the top of the sidemenu will be shown to viewers regardless of which part of the page they are viewing at that moment. 
However, I find it quite hard to combine these with a way to make the page return to the scroll point that the visitor was at, after the sidemenu has disappeared. Could you help me with this?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav" id="sidemenu">
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolo</a></li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#sidebutton').click(function() {
$('#sidemenu').toggleClass("current") && $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
$('.nodisplay').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

CSS (just in case):

```
 #sidemenu, .hidden {  display: none; }
 #sidemenu.current { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the menu is hidden, save the current scroll position somewhere (local/sessionStorage, variable, where ever) and scroll to top. When the menu is not hidden, scroll to the position you previously saved:

```
var scrollTo;
var prevScrolPos;

$('#sidebutton').click(function () {

    if (!$('#sidemenu').hasClass("current")) {
        // if the menu is hidden, save the current scroll position and scroll to top
        prevScrolPos = $('body').scrollTop();
        scrollTo = 0;
    } else {
        // if the menu is not hidden, scroll to the saved position
        scrollTo = prevScrolPos;
    }

    $('#sidemenu').toggleClass("current") && $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollTo);
    $('.nodisplay').toggleClass("hidden");

});
```

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o7btkgog/

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong while trying to apply it -- although even as I go through your demo, I can't get to my previous scroll position after the sidemenu is disappeared again. Could be something that I'm missing?

Comment: For me the demo is working fine. If you have trouble applying it to your code, make sure you are saving the scroll position of the element that has the scroll. That could be the window, body, html etc. Here's an updated demo which uses the scrollTop of the window: http://jsfiddle.net/o7btkgog/1/

Comment: For some reason, even the second demo doesn't work for me. It scrolls to the top of the page but never returns to the previous position. I tried using window, 'body', 'html', even 'html, body', but nothing worked. I am at a loss.

Comment: It turned out that I had to place the line "$('.nodisplay').toggleClass("hidden");" before the "$('#sidemenu').toggleClass("current") && $('html,body').scrollTop(scrollTo);" for this to work for me. Once again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the scroll position when the user clicks on the button to show the sidebar, you can store it on `localStorage` and then when the sidebar is closed you scrollback to the stored position.

Here is an example of how you will grab it, execute this when you are about to show the side menu:

```
var currentScrollPosition = $('body')[0].scrollTop;
localStorage.setItem('myapp-current-top', currentScrollPosition);
```

Then when you want to return the scroll to that position you just pass that value to the scrollTop() function like this:

```
$('body').scrollTop(localStorage.getItem('myapp-current-top'));
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What you said sounds very interesting, the problem is that I don't really know much about JS to be able to apply this myself. I can only adjust snippets, not create them myself. Sorry if that sounds too demanding.

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example of how to achieve the solution, I hope it helps you :D.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the extra effort. Unfortunately, it appears that I'm much worse than I thought I was at implementing things, it behaves as if nothing has changed in the code. I will totally understand if you just give up on me :P